# Autohotkey Fallback if Program doesn't exist

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to have my cygwin **sh** program open when I hit Windows Key + R (this could just as easily apply to any other key combination), but I realize that all of my computers may not have cygwin installed.  In the case where my computer doesn't have cygwin, I'd like to just open the Windows Command Prompt.

How do I conditionally set the `#r` (Win+R) mapping to attain this?

Comment: Windows Key + R is already mapped to bring up the run prompt. It might be easier to go for an unclaimed key combination than re-writing system behavior.

Comment: @SpecKK: Nope; it's pretty easy for me to overwrite that behavior.  I've mapped Win+R to *cmd* for quite a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@yhw42's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/198320/autohotkey-fallback-if-program-doesnt-exist/198325#198325) did get me started, but I've found a cleaner solution:

```
WinR := "sh"
RunWait, where sh
if ErrorLevel
    WinR := "cmd"

#r::Run %WinR%
```

This uses the Windows `WHERE` command and [AutoHotkey variables](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm).

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works on Windows Server 2003 or later (i.e. not Windows XP).

Comment: That is better! (i.e. check once when the script is loaded)

Answer (score 3):

This is untested, but should get you started:

```
#r::
Run sh
WinWait,sh,,1
if ErrorLevel
{
   ;it timed out waiting for sh (1 sec)
   Run cmd
}
return
```

It attempts to run the `sh` cygwin command. Using the [WinWait](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWait.htm) function, it checks to see if it was created (using a window title of "sh", that may need to be changed). If not, it falls back to `run cmd`.

Another option, if you always know the absolute path of `sh.exe`, you can use the [FileExist](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#FileExist) method.

```
#r::
if FileExist("c:\cygwin\sh.exe")
   Run sh
else
   Run cmd
return
```